# Open a read-only Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a program (zTree) that is writing an Excel file and updating it constantly. What I need this Python program to do is read in the data from the Excel file as its updating. The problem that I'm having though is that when I try to read in the data using xlrd, I get the error:

```
    peek = f.read(peeksz)
IO Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

which comes up because Excel is in read-only mode. Is there any way to read in the data of an Excel file in read-only mode using Python?

Comment: Is it in read-only mode or more probably in write-only mode?

Comment: If I try to open it with Excel, I get that the file is locked for editing by another user and that I can only open it in read-only mode

Comment: that doesn't look like xlrd code to me, can you post a more complete sample?  (I was expecting something like `peek = xlrd.open_workbook(peeksz)` where `peeksz` is the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just tested it on win 7 (64bit), but in this case it works:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:/User/myaccount/Book1.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
print worksheet
```

could it be, that you are trying to copy it first, or that your python is trying to put a temporary copy of the file in the py-directoy? - because that would give the IO-Error